Statistical Test for Difference in non-paired proportions
I want to do a statistical test for a relatively simple scenario. But in my research, I could not find a straightforward answer how to compute this.
There is an experimental setup where one group receives a treatment and the other not (control group). The treatment tries to increase a behavior.
In the control group, men show the behavior 60% of the time. Women show the behavior 50% of the time.
In the treatment group, men show the behavior 68% of the time (i.e. increase of 8%, statistically significant) and women show the behavior 52% of the time (i.e. increase of 12%, also significant).
I know want to know is the difference in increase (4%) statistically significant? I.e. I want to test if "the treatment worked better (caused a greater increase) for women than for men".
How can I test that? Thank you for your help.
